# Magento 2 - Show Selected Out of Stock products in Catalog

Tags: magento2, stock

On my website, Display Out of Stock Products is set to `No`

But I need to show some out-of-stock products in category listing based on the attribute `Coming Soon` set to `true`.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Did you ever find a working solution to this question of yours?

Answer (score 0):

So here's what I would try:

1) Set to yes the Display out of Stock

2) Disable the products out of the stock that you don't want to show (or just put them not visible)

3) After go create a catalog product list widget in the widget section. During the process you can set conditions that met your requirements and you can set the widget title to "Coming soon".

Thats what I would try first, wish that help you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I do not wish to disable out of stock product.

Comment: Then, just put all the products that you want to show in the "coming soon" in the same category and base your widget conditions on that.

Comment: I guess I am not clear in my question, I need to show in stock and coming soon product (which are out of stock) in category listing. I want to extend $productcollection

Comment: Do you want all your "out of stock" products become "coming soon" or just few ones and the others stay "out of stock" ?

Comment: Just few ones with attribute coming soon (but stock status will be out of stock) along with product in stock in category listing.

Comment: So if I understand, you want to show certain "out of stock" products in the category that contain all your "in stock" products ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am looking for.

Comment: So the only thing I see for the moment is with widget. You can set the title of the widget to "coming soon" and apply the widget in the anchor category that you wish.

Comment: But if you find a way that all your "out of stock" would be "coming soon" you can change it with the translate inline in "store --> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer" . I know it's not your case right now, but if you can find a way, it would work exactly as you want.